# ZFS zpool cannot be imported, cause panic if not imported as readonly

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, zfs, read-only, kernel-panic, zpool

After a reboot, ZFS pool never stopped trying to import the pool. It was blocking the boot-sequence and I had to rename the /etc/zfs/zpool.cache to another name, in order to boot the system.
There was an upgrade made before reboot, but that was not anything with zfs.

The problem is that zpool datastore is not possible to import in normal way. Only in readonly=on is I able to import it.
Also the Scub seems to be active on the readonly, but it will never stops since it not possible to write to the pool.
I cannot stop scrub either since I can only import it at readonly.

If I import it at readonly it works and I can access the files. But if import normally a panic occur, and the process hangs.

Any suggestions what can be the issue ?

```
#lsb_release -rd
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:        18.04

#apt-cache policy zfsutils-linux
zfsutils-linux:
  Installed: 0.7.5-1ubuntu16.9
  Candidate:    0.7.5-1ubuntu16.9


# dpkg -l | grep -i "zfs"

rc  libzfs1                                0.6.2-1~precise                                 amd64        Native ZFS filesystem library for Linux

rc  libzfs2                                0.6.5.4-1~precise                               amd64        Native OpenZFS filesystem library for Linux

ii  libzfs2linux                           0.7.5-1ubuntu16.9                               amd64        OpenZFS filesystem library for Linux

rc  libzpool1                              0.6.2-1~precise                                 amd64        Native ZFS pool library for Linux

rc  libzpool2                              0.6.5.4-1~precise                               amd64        Native OpenZFS pool library for Linux

ii  libzpool2linux                         0.7.5-1ubuntu16.9                               amd64        OpenZFS pool library for Linux

rc  ubuntu-zfs                             8~precise                                       amd64        Native ZFS filesystem metapackage for Ubuntu.

rc  zfs-dkms                               0.7.5-1ubuntu16.9                               all          OpenZFS filesystem kernel modules for Linux

ii  zfs-doc                                0.7.5-1ubuntu16.9                               all          Native OpenZFS filesystem documentation and examples.

ii  zfs-initramfs                          0.7.5-1ubuntu16.9                               all          OpenZFS root filesystem capabilities for Linux - initramfs

ii  zfs-zed                                0.7.5-1ubuntu16.9                               amd64        OpenZFS Event Daemon

rc  zfsutils                               0.6.5.4-1~precise                               amd64        Native OpenZFS management utilities for Linux

ii  zfsutils-linux                         0.7.5-1ubuntu16.9                               amd64        command-line tools to manage OpenZFS filesystems
```

And some zpool status

```
#zpool status
no pools available

# zpool import
   pool: datastore
     id: 3190464655986727485
  state: ONLINE
 status: Some supported features are not enabled on the pool.
 action: The pool can be imported using its name or numeric identifier, though
        some features will not be available without an explicit 'zpool upgrade'.
 config:

        datastore   ONLINE
          raidz2-0  ONLINE
            sdb     ONLINE
            sdc     ONLINE
            sdd     ONLINE
            sde     ONLINE
            sdf     ONLINE
            sdg     ONLINE



# zpool import -o readonly=on datastore
# zpool status
  pool: datastore
 state: ONLINE
status: Some supported features are not enabled on the pool. The pool can
        still be used, but some features are unavailable.
action: Enable all features using 'zpool upgrade'. Once this is done,
        the pool may no longer be accessible by software that does not support
        the features. See zpool-features(5) for details.
  scan: scrub in progress since Sun May 10 00:24:01 2020
        15,1T scanned out of 15,1T at 1B/s, (scan is slow, no estimated time)
        1,44M repaired, 100,01% done
config:

        NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        datastore   ONLINE       0     0     0
          raidz2-0  ONLINE       0     0     0
            sdb     ONLINE       0     0     0
            sdc     ONLINE       0     0     0
            sdd     ONLINE       0     0     0
            sde     ONLINE       0     0     0
            sdf     ONLINE       0     0     0
            sdg     ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

If I now tries to import the datastore in normal way, it Panic and hangs.

```
#zpool export datastore
#zpool import -F datastore

VERIFY3(c < (1ULL << 24) >> 9) failed (36028797018963967 < 32768)
PANIC at zio.c:266:zio_buf_alloc()
```

I also tried to use zdb to see if it could find any errors. This gets interrupted after a while.

```
#set zfs:zfs_recover=1
#set aok=1
#zdb -e -bcsvL datastore

Traversing all blocks to verify checksums ...

2.29T completed ( 144MB/s) estimated time remaining: 25hr 46min 43sec        c < (1ULL << 24) >> 9 (0x7fffffffffffff < 0x8000)
ASSERT at ../../module/zfs/zio.c:266:zio_buf_alloc()Aborted (SIGABRT)
```

Answer (score 0):

In order, things to try:

1) Import read-only, run a scrub, wait for it to complete. Then try importing read-write again.

2) Upgrade to latest ZoL (0.8.4). A a lot of fixes went in since ZFS 0.7.5. Do NOT do `zpool upgrade`. Then re-do point 1).

Is the machine stable? No MCEs or disk errors in the logs or SMART?

Comment: 1) scrub cannot run in read-only, and cannot write to zpool metadata in read only.
2) I updated to 0.8.3, but the same issue still occurs. Will try to update or at least see if additional
3) currently checking..